# "invalid cross-thread access" when calculating a route - Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, windows-phone

i'm trying to show a route on a map, but i get this exception. i can't figure out why. 
here is my codebehind:

```
public partial class map_new : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public GeoCoordinate destination;
    public GeoCoordinate myPosition;
    public Geolocator myGeolocator;
    List<GeoCoordinate> waypoints = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
    public RouteQuery routeQuery;


    public map_new()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        destination = new GeoCoordinate(41.909859, 12.461792);
        ShowDestinationLocationOnTheMap();

        myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        myGeolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        myGeolocator.MovementThreshold = 20; // The units are meters.
        myGeolocator.StatusChanged+=geolocator_StatusChanged;


    }

    private async Task update_position() 
    {
        Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        myPosition = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.myMap.Center = myPosition;
            this.myMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
        });
        //update_route();
    }

    private async void update_route()
    {
        await update_position();
        RouteQuery routeQuery = new RouteQuery();
        waypoints.Add(myPosition);
        waypoints.Add(destination);
        routeQuery.Waypoints = waypoints;
        routeQuery.QueryCompleted += routeQuery_QueryCompleted;
        routeQuery.QueryAsync();
    }

    void routeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Route MyRoute = e.Result;
            MapRoute MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
            myMap.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);
            routeQuery.Dispose();
        }
    }

    void geolocator_StatusChanged(Geolocator sender, StatusChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        string status = "";

        switch (args.Status)
        {

            case PositionStatus.Ready:
                // the location service is generating geopositions as specified by the tracking parameters
                status = "ready";
                update_route();
                break;

    }
```

i think the error is that update_route() don't wait for update_position() to be completed, but i don't how to set update_route() to wait.
any idea?

EDIT: after applying KooKiz and Stephen solution the error is located on this line:

```
RouteQuery routeQuery = new RouteQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "invalid cross-thread access" usually occurs when trying to update the UI from a background thread. In your case, I believe it's when you try to update the `myMap` control.

To update the control from the UI thread, you can use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method:

```
private async void update_position() 
{
    Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
    myPosition = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
            this.myMap.Center = myPosition;
            this.myMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
    });
    //update_route();
}
```

**Edit:** Apparently, the RouteQuery object also need to be instantiated on the UI thread. Then I suggest calling the whole `update_route` method on the UI:

```
        case PositionStatus.Ready:
            // the location service is generating geopositions as specified by the tracking parameters
            status = "ready";
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => update_route());
            break;
```

(and then remove the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from the `update_position` method)

Comment: applied your solution but still get the error, check the updated main question

Comment: ok that seeems to work, a route is showed, but immediatly after that a NullReferenceException is trowed by 
'routeQuery.Dispose();'
why?

Comment: @JacopoGrassi Replace `RouteQuery routeQuery = new RouteQuery();` by `routeQuery = new RouteQuery();`, otherwise you're creating a local variable and not using the field you declared before (the `public RouteQuery routeQuery;` part)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `async void`. Instead, use `async Task`, which allows you to `await` the returned `Task`. `async void` should only be used for event handlers.

I have an [introduction to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.

Comment: applied your solution but still get the error, check the updated main question